# Direct HTML/JS connection with Local SQL Server Instance

Tags: javascript, html, sql, sql-server, database

I have been trying to connect my html/js to my local sql server instance, and it's not happening.
I'm fairly new to JS-to-SQL coding, so i did some digging online and found a thread on Connection using ActiveX. That did not go well because it only responds on IE, all the other browsers don't even see the code.
I will be greatly thankful if someone can point me in a way to just simply read and write data on my trusted sql server db from my simple input html form directly and locally.
Any help would be Greatly appreciated.
Thank You!

Comment: That is not how normal browser works, for example any website would be able to mess with your database server. Maybe look into NodeJS or Electronjs?

Comment: i have tried node.js but whenever i insert the command 'node server.js', it just stands there for hours doing nothing. PLUS. I have no actual clue on how to use node.js. Sorry about that.

Comment: Accessing SQL server "directly from html/js" is a super-mega-ultra-T1000-bad idea and the reason why other browsers "don't see the code", so depending on what are you doing you should look into alternative languages or introduce an API and use it to communicate with the database.